# Calculate time difference in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

- I have a Dictionary called d, which maps different number of dates
  for each key. I have multiple keys.
- What I really want to do, is to calculate the total time difference
  between the earliest and latest date for each key.
- I have tried few different ways but nothing works, as I don't seem to
  be able to access the values sequentially and perform operations.

This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
Patient_Dates = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1', header=0, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "B:C") 
    
Patient_Dates_new = Patient_Dates.iloc[3:len(Patient_Dates)]  
Patient_Dates_new.columns = ['Patient_ID','Dates']  
    
counts = {k: count(0) for k in Patient_Dates_new.Patient_ID.unique()} 
    
d = defaultdict(dict)  
    
for k, *v in Patient_Dates_new.values.tolist():     
    d[k][next(counts[k])] = v  dict(d) Dictd=dict(d)
```

Comment: where are the images?

Comment: Thank you, I just uploaded one (the webpage only allowed my one image). Any ideas?

Comment: `calculate the total time difference between the earliest and latest date for each key` - I see only 1 element for each key, what do you want to do with that list?

Comment: Please provide some of your attempts so we can help you from there:)

Comment: If you notice, there are multiple values within each key. In there you see all dates for one key.

Comment: you are saying that these 9 `datetime`s belong to 1 key?

Comment: Yes, these 9 datetimes belong to just one key. I have multiple other keys with other datetimes (some have less some have more datetimes).

Comment: I don't have code I am afraid. The reason is that I don't know how to loop through each value per key, in order to perform the calculation. Should I use something like:              
for key, value in d.items(): ??

Comment: Are these 9 datetimes in a list stored under one key?

Comment: Yes, these 9 datetime belong to one key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code below will do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

#Create dictionary with diffrent 'lists' of 'datetime' as values
my_dictionary = {
    "1": [datetime.now() + timedelta(days = x) for x in range(0, 10)], 
    "2": [datetime.now() + timedelta(days = x) for x in range(10, 20)], 
    "3": [datetime.now() + timedelta(days = x) for x in range(20, 30)], 
}

for value in my_dictionary.values(): #Iterate through every KEY
    value.sort() #Sort the list

    print("Time diffrence between min. {} and max. {} is: {}".format(value[0], value[-1], value[0] - value[-1]))
```

1. First we create a `dictionary` with `lists` of `datetime objects` (for this we use Python's oneliners)
2. Then we iterate through every item in the `dictionary`.
3. We then `sort` every `list` and calculate the difference between `first (min)` and `last (max)` item.

Comment: Thank you very much Jakub. I think it will work. Only a minor point, when I run this, it gives me an error though: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'.

Comment: That is strange because for me it works without any errors. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yes I copied the code correctly and it did work for your example. The problem was that it did not work for my dictionary (I notice the "values" look different in my keys, is this part of the reason?).

Comment: As you said your `dictionary` has` keys` with `lists` of `datatime` objects as value correct? If this is the case then my example must work or through you some other error. What i think is happening is that your dictionary is formated in a diffrent way. Please post a snippet code of how you get the dictionary and how it looks. I will look on it tommorow.

Comment: Thank you Jakub, here it is (I use the "Dictd" at the end, in the place of your "my_dictionary"):

`Patient_Dates = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Data.xlsx',
                   sheet_name='Sheet 1', header=0, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "B:C")
Patient_Dates_new=Patient_Dates.iloc[3:len(Patient_Dates)]

Patient_Dates_new.columns = ['Patient_ID','Dates']

counts = {k: count(0) for k in Patient_Dates_new.Patient_ID.unique()}
d = defaultdict(dict)

for k, *v in Patient_Dates_new.values.tolist():
    d[k][next(counts[k])] = v

dict(d)
Dictd=dict(d)`